# Using MasterPages in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a few pages on my application now and I am going to start using a master page to low the amount of code in my HTML. So I created a 'Web form using master page' and at the moment I have a menu bar I have created in there:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PersonnelMasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="bSimplex.Personnel.PersonnelMasterPage" %>


    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cnt_MenuBar" runat="server">
            <div class="bsimplex header-bar left">
        <div class="header-context clearfix header-label">
            <asp:Image ID="bsimplexPTLogo" runat="server" CssClass="small-logo" ImageUrl="~/Images/tracker logoOnly.png" />
            <label class="configurationlbl">Personnel Tracker</label>
        </div>
        <div class="menubarbest">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li  class="current"><a href="bPersonnelTrackerDashboard.aspx" >Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Manager</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Rota</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Holiday Requests</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Absences</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="bSicknessForm.aspx">Sickness</a></li>
                        <li><a href="bLatenessForm.aspx">Lateness</a></li>
                        <li><a href="bMedicalLeaveForm.aspx">Medical Appointment</a></li>
                        <li><a href="OtherMedical.aspx">Other</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Attendance Record</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rota</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Admin/Administration.aspx">Admin</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Then on the Web Form i just created i have added this Content Holder:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Personnel/PersonnelMasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="bSimplex.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cnt_MenuBar" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

**Firstly**, nothing is showing on my page and I am wondering have I done something wrong?

**Secondly**, I have CSS styles for this menu bar will these stay the same or because I have moved into Master page will they need to be changed?

Comment: If you want to show MenuBar in all pages,why are you again overriding in child page. Don't include any Content control for "cnt_MenuBar" in child pages

Comment: @malkam Where am I overriding it? I'm confused as to calling the master page menu bar.

Comment: <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cnt_MenuBar" runat="server">
</asp:Content> in child page will set blank. Declare one more ContentPlaceHolder in Master Page to render rest of html,keeping cnt_menubar to display Menu in all pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you want to share the menu across multiple pages, so I would try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bsimplex header-bar left">
        <div class="header-context clearfix header-label">
            <asp:Image ID="bsimplexPTLogo" runat="server" CssClass="small-logo" ImageUrl="~/Images/tracker logoOnly.png" />
            <label class="configurationlbl">Personnel Tracker</label>
        </div>
        <div class="menubarbest">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li  class="current"><a href="bPersonnelTrackerDashboard.aspx" >Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Manager</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Rota</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Holiday Requests</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Absences</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="bSicknessForm.aspx">Sickness</a></li>
                        <li><a href="bLatenessForm.aspx">Lateness</a></li>
                        <li><a href="bMedicalLeaveForm.aspx">Medical Appointment</a></li>
                        <li><a href="OtherMedical.aspx">Other</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Attendance Record</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rota</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Admin/Administration.aspx">Admin</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cnt_Body" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then on the WebForms page, do something like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Personnel/PersonnelMasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="bSimplex.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cnt_Body" runat="server">
    <h1>Sickness Form</h1>
    <p>Please fill out the following sickness form...</p>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer worked fine, Just 2 questions. Firstly, My CSS styling now doesn't appear. How do I link the styling back up to the master page? Secondly, I don't understand how CPH in the masterpage isn't wrapped around the content, but still knows it needs that?

Comment: You need to link to the CSS from the master page so that any child pages will have the appropriate styling already. And what do you mean by "isn't wrapped around the content"?

Comment: @mason At the bottom of the Master page you have the CHP called 'cnt_body' with nothing inside it. How does that contentplaceholder know what content have in it? Will it take all content from that MasterPage?

Comment: @user3129331 The Content Page "knows" about the ContentPlaceHolders on the Master Page. When the user requests the page, the Content areas from the child pages are merged into the corresponding ContentPlaceHolders on the master page. Go try it out, implement Ben's code and it should be quite clear how it works. Also have a look at the link I provided in the comment on my answer.

Comment: @mason I think I understand, does that mean then if I want to add something to that master page that I only want to use on half of the pages would that not be possible? Unless I use 2 master pages?

Comment: There's several ways to do it. You could create a ContentPlaceHolder and put the content inside it, then just not create the corresponding Content controls on the child pages. Or you could create two master pages. Or you could do nested master pages. Remember this principle though: Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY). So two master pages should probably only be used if they're going to be completely different if you're trying to follow the DRY principle.

Comment: @mason Ahh I understand thanks for clearing that up for me, Last question, when I call the stylesheet from my master page so the styling can get added it doesn't work?

Comment: @user3129331 I would make a separate question for that issue. It's best to stick with one SO question per question!

Comment: @user3129331 I agree with mason, that's probably a good question to ask separately. But I did edit the original code sample to demonstrate how external css files could be linked from the master page. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @BenHarrison I understand thanks for your Help Ben and Mason helped me alot to understand. The CSS will still not work going to look into it abit more before asking a question. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

On your master page, don't put content *inside* the ContentPlaceHolder. The CPH is an area where you want to put child page content (using the Content control).

On your master page, if you put content inside a ContentPlaceHolder, it will be overridden if you add a corresponding Content control on the child page. So most of the time you don't put anything inside the CPH on the master page. The exception is if you want some "default" content that you might override on certain child pages.

By the way, your top level master page should contain the basic layout of your site, and all the required tags (ex: `<html><head><title><body>` etc). Then, you put those ContentPlaceHolders in places where you want the child page to add its content.

Your CSS should be fine without changes, although you'll want to link to it from the master page instead of the child pages.

Comment: I'm so confused. Do I not call the contentplaceholder with the content tag on my child pages?

Comment: You can, if you want the child page to have content. The master page is merged with child pages when it's rendered to the client. Anywhere the master page has a ContentPlaceHolder, that's where the child page's content can go. So for example, you might have different ContentPlaceHolder areas for MainContent, LeftSidebar, RightSidebar, and Footer. Just depends on your layout. Checkout [Master Pages on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The placeholder element is an area that will vary from page to page. I don't think you'd want the menu bar to vary. So, place the menu bar code before the placeholder in the masterpage or better yet inside a user control